# Show that if $\vdash A_{m+1}$, then $ A_1,...,A_m \vdash B$ if and only if $ A_1,...,A_m,A_{m+1} \vdash B$.

Tags: propositional-calculus, proof-theory

This question concerns propositional logic.  The $\vdash$ symbol refers to deductibility.  How do I prove this without using the fact that propositional logic is consistent? Thanks.

Show that if $\vdash A_{m+1}$, then $ A_1,...,A_m \vdash B$ if and only if $ A_1,...,A_m,A_{m+1} \vdash B$.

Comment: By the properties of $\vdash$, you can always add "unused" premsies; thus, if $A_1, \ldots,A_m ⊢ B$, then trivially: $A_1, \ldots,A_{m+1} ⊢ B$.

Answer (score 1):

The [derivability relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)): $\vdash$ has the following property (also called [Weakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule)):

> if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Gamma'$, then $\Gamma' \vdash \varphi$.

We can use it for half of the needed result:

> if $A_1,\ldots,A_m⊢B$, we can add an additional premise to get: $A_1,\ldots,A_m,A_{m+1} ⊢ B$.

For the other part, we can use the [Deduction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem):

> from $A_1,\ldots,A_m,A_{m+1}⊢B$, we can derive: $A_1,\ldots,A_m ⊢ A_{m+1} → B$.

Then, we can use $⊢A_{m+1}$ and *modus ponens* to get: $A_1,\ldots,A_m⊢B$.